# How To Keep Properties File outside the war in spring application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, properties

I was trying to implement reloadable message resource in my spring application using the following example [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658657/externalized-message-properties-file-is-not-picking-up-in-tomcat)

1. But I am not getting an idea on how and when the class Message will be instantiated. should i declare this as a bean in the spring.xml?
2. How the method setMessageSource will be called?
3. Whats the significance of BUNDLE_NAME = "com.sample.project.core.ui.resources.messages". How this is used in the application.

Please revert back if you have any solution for these questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to externalize the strings and access them in your application or do you want to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can declare the class as a @configuration class. Then make sure you scan the package of your class so the configuration is discovered by Spring at startup.
2. In the example, the call to setMessageSource is done "manually" whenever the bundle needs to be reloaded. You need to implement a strategy to call the methods when appropriate.
3. the bundle name follows the i18n standard. Basically, your message bundle would normaly be found under the folder com/sample/project/core/ui/resources/messages

Answer (score 0):

Can deploy the exploded war. its just a zip, so put the unziped version in the app container. Either change build to make a ecploded war or if unfamiliar just use 7zip to 'extract' war to a new folder then put that folder into tomcat or other app containers appropriate webapps folder. jsut make sure the WEB-INF folder is below the main folder of your exploded app

Means folder struc:

```
tomcat
   -conf
   -bin
   -webapps 
      -yourApp
        -WEB-INF
```

Then you can edit the property files with less trouble. But need to remember to keep a copy of the property files in case you deploy a new version of app. Good to keem them in source control under a prod-conf or other folder.